# groupPadding for stacking series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

In short, I need to somehow enable `groupPadding` for stacked series. It looks a little bit odd, but this is what you can do in PowerPoint if you set `series overlap` to 0:[image]

With `series overlap` set to 100, they would be on top of each other like in Highcharts with `stacking` set to e.g. `normal`.
To me, it seems you are not allowed to move stacking columns horizontally relative to each other in Highcharts. But maybe I am missing something or there is a workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional hidden series with the same stack as the upper series. Example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', { 
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPadding: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y}%'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: data2,
        color: 'gray'
    }, {
        data: data1,
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        linkedTo: 'data1',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, {
        id: 'data1',
        data: data1,
        stack: 'A',
        color: 'green'
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rkvs8cy7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stack